Git pull / push works in MacOS Terminal but not VS Code
I've read so many SE Questions but nothing.
In MacOS Terminal:
user@mac repo-name % git pull
Already up to date.

VS Code:
node ➜ /workspaces/repo-name (main) $ git pull
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I tried several solutions like:

Does nothing: git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo-name.git
Does nothing: Delete Github
Keychain from Macos Keychines
Does Nothing: A solution which prints
the executable which git and then put that path into vs code
settings

In the Gui of Git Tower everything works nicely as well
What else to try?

It seems like VS Code is unable to find your SSH key. You will need to find the steps to configure VS Code properly or add the SSH key where VS Code can find it.

Can you check pwd (the current directory) in each terminal and make sure they both see the same location?
